# Install Ubuntu 2019

Tags: system-installation

I am trying install Ubuntu on my [Acer One 10 1002 Convertible 2-in-1 / Tablet & Notebook](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/6142?b=1) with an Intel [Atom 3735f](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/80274/intel-atom-processor-z3735f-2m-cache-up-to-1-83-ghz.html) CPU. Windows 10 (32-bit) and bloatware are preinstalled.

I tried some USB to bootable USB software like [Rufus](https://rufus.ie), [Lili](https://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/news/item/new-stable-version), [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) ... but I have never managed to boot from a USB with the boot loader.

When I selected my USB drive it takes me to the UEFI/BIOS ( have to figure that out somehow too) or straight back to Windows 10.

I already disabled safe boot and set my boot order correctly.

I also tried the [refind](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/REFInd) method where I mount a volume but I could never change to the recommended S: directory with the refind folder to rename things.

There must be some way to install it and remove Windows 10 from my machine!

Comment: Are you trying to install 19.04 or 19.10 ? Do you have the Legacy/BIOS boot method enabled? If so, please switch to UEFI in your BIOS/firmware setup.

Comment: Ok I got my problem my device uses a 32 bit boot loader so I needed a respin version of the iso.

Comment: OBTW, the Lili LiveUSB generator has been out of support for two years and change, so Rufus and Unetbootin are much better choices.  You will see links to all three above in your question now.  I'd also suggest, when you do install, that you keep the Windows 10 but shrink the NTFS partition down to 10GB more than the space it takes now, to minimize the room it takes. You might need it for testing some day, handy to have it on your drive if needed.

Comment: ok thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you need 32-bit, there's a 32-bit [Lubuntu 18.04 LTS](http://lubuntu.me/downloads) and a 32-bit [Xubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://xubuntu.org/download).  Given the small amount of memory your Atom based system has, I recommend Lubuntu or Xubuntu over Ubuntu with the demanding GNOME DE.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out:
I have 64 bit processor with a 32 bit bootloader:

1. a.  Create a respin iso like [here](http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2017/03/running-ubuntu-with-upstream-kernel-on.html)

   b. Or download one [here](https://linuxminipcs.wordpress.com/ubuntu-18-04-2-lts-bionic-beaver/)
2. Use [rufus](https://rufus.ie/de_DE.html) or any other bootable usb creater
3. Go into your Uefi disable secure boot
4. Change your bootorder and put your Uefi USB on 1
5. Exit and save
6. A reboot should take you to an options window or enter Bootmenu (on my acer it is f12)
7. Install Ubuntu or try it
8. Done !

Special thanks all the fast answers and to [this](https://community.acer.com/de/discussion/533059/linux-auf-acer-one-10-s1003-installieren)
forum answer and of course to [this awesome guy](http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/)